# Cannot add a Gif to a JLabel in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, icons, gif

I need to be able to add a gif to a JLabel and I have searched google many times already. This is my code. I simply added the gif to the JLabel and ran the application:

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package WorkPointDashboard3;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *

*/
public class WorkPointDashboard extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
/**
 * Creates new form WorkPointDashboard
 */
public WorkPointDashboard() {
    initComponents();
    setIcon();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialise the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("WorkPoint");
    setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    setExtendedState(getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

    jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/WorkPointDashboard3/LogoMain.png"))); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(483, 483, 483)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap(508, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(258, 258, 258)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap(456, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */

    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(WorkPointDashboard.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        new WorkPointDashboard().setVisible(true);
    });
}

private void setIcon() {
    setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("LogoMain.png")));
}









// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: It seems like you're adding a png file not a gif?

Comment: “I simply added the gif to the JLabel and ran the application”  … and then what happened?  You told us what you want to do, but you forgot to describe the problem you’re having.